# Open Data Portal/Software for Live Measurements: is there any?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, time-series, real-time

I am working in **meteorology/glaciology**. We have quite a lot of observations (partly live!) and we would like to **publish these data (live!)** to the world.

So what we are looking for is a portal/software that allows publishing such "time series" data. This would include data such as temperature measurements, precipitation measurements, maybe glacier length changes, and so far and so on.

There is a chance to get some money of the national science fund - smaller projects to **make data** from past projects **available to all** of you. As I could not find anything suitable on the web:

- **Is there something like this** but I was too stupid to find it?
- **If not**: do you think that there is **a need for it**?

The idea - if not yet available - would be an open source software including a flexible backend, data upload interface (e.g., xml data xchange via scp/ftp/web upload), and a frontend offering "simple" data series plots, data exports, and that the uploader/maintainer of these data sets can write/upload notes, manuals, important information (e.g., instrument correction coefficients, when instruments have been maintained/replaced, ...).

Thank you very much for the input! We are currently in a "discussion" or "rough project planning" phase and all comments or hints will be more than helpful!

Comment: Have a look at my question/answer for glacier databases: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7919/11218

Comment: I was wondering if you've already published this data, (if so, where?) or if it's still being worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usual suspects:
[CKAN](http://ckan.org/)
[JKAN](https://github.com/timwis/jkan)

[Plenario.io seems to be something along what you want...but I may be mistaken here](http://plenar.io/)

NASA seems like they will/do have a solution for this: they publish vast quantities of data, that sound very similar to what yours sound like. It may be worth your while to check out:
[NASA Open Source Software](http://code.nasa.gov/)
[openNASA](https://open.nasa.gov/)
[NASA's GitHub Profile](https://github.com/nasa)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! That helped me a lot, especially the CKAN (PostgreSQL/python backend, modular framework) looks awesome. I now have to dig deeper in the specs of all you suggested, but that saved my day :).

Comment: np. glad you chose ckan. its great.